# New syntax for click event in Handlebars/EmberJS

Tags: ember.js, handlebars.js

How do I switch from:

```
 <Checkbox
   //do I need it to be @onclick?
   onclick={{action "toggleCheckBox" checkBox}}
 />
```

to:

```
 <Checkbox
  {{on "click" this.toggleCheckBox "test"}}
 />
```

given that I'm not using a class for my controller:

```
import Controller from '@ember/controller';

export default Controller.extend({
  actions: {
    toggleCheckBox(checkBox) {
      //code
    }
  }
})
```

Comment: you could just do `{{on "click" (action "toggleCheckBox" checkBox)}}` for the time being.

Answer (score 1):

Even though you can use new `on` modifier syntax in classic ember class model with some syntax tweaks, it **works best with Native class syntax** as the context binding was moved from `{{action}}` helper to `@action` decorator. The decorator usage is intuitive with the Native class syntax.

1) For some reason, if you still need to use `on` modifier with classic ember model, you can wrap your function with the `action` decorator definition (decorators in Ember are fully backwards compatible) to bind the proper `this` context to the function. Otherwise, you cannot access proper `this` inside your function.

```js
import Controller from '@ember/controller';
import { action } from '@ember/object';

export default Controller.extend({
  toggleCheckBox: action(function(checkBox) {
    //code
  })
})
```

However, the above snippet is less intuitive compared to the actual native class syntax:

```js
import Controller from '@ember/controller';
import { action } from '@ember/object';

export default AppController extends Controller {
  @action
  toggleCheckBox(checkBox) {
    //code
  }
}
```

2) `fn` helper has to be used to pass arguments to the handler when using `on` modifier.

```html
<Checkbox
 {{on "click" (fn this.toggleCheckBox "test")}}
/>
```

[This Twiddle](https://ember-twiddle.com/7a3f537f4282f07c44d22853b6b4daf7?openFiles=templates.application%5C.hbs%2Ctemplates.components.my-component%5C.hbs) should help to play around the syntaxes. Here is the [upgrade guide](https://guides.emberjs.com/release/upgrading/current-edition/action-on-and-fn/) to move from classic event handlers to new Octanish syntax. [Chris's explanation](https://www.pzuraq.com/ember-octane-update-action/) provides an in-depth explanation about the newer syntaxes.

Answer (score -1):

Another possible solution is usage of ember render-modifiers. Every time the checkbox is pressed, the action will be called.

```
<Input @class="form-control" @type="checkbox" @checked={{item.checked}} {{did-update this.foo item.checked item}}/>

@action
foo(e, item){
   console.log(item[0], item[1]);
}
```

Where "observed" item[0] holds checked value, and item[1] whole object